# Some questions about nested intervals and their theorem

Tags: real-analysis

In a lecture we covered the *nested intervals theorem*, which was formulated that way (I try to translate from french, so please forgive me if I make mistakes):

> Let $\{I_n\}_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$  be nested, closed (and bounded) sets. Then there exists $x \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $x \in I_n$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$.

My first question is the following: **why does this theorem require the sets to be bounded?** (I understand why they need to be closed, because there are counterexamples if they are open sets, but I don't really understand why they need to be bounded, and what would exactly happen if they were not bounded.)

While looking for informations on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Completeness_of_the_real_numbers#Nested_intervals_theorem) about this, another (probably dumb) question arised: the article says:

> The rational number line does not satisfy the nested interval theorem. For example, the sequence (whose terms are derived from the digits of pi in the suggested way)
>   $$[3,4] \supset [3.1,3.2] \supset [3.14,3.15] \supset [3.141,3.142] \supset \cdots$$ 
>   is a nested sequence of closed intervals in the rational numbers whose intersection is empty. (In the real numbers, the intersection of these intervals contains the number pi.)

But **why is the intersection of these intervals empty?** I know that a "basic" answer could be "because $\pi$ belongs to the real numbers but not to the rationals", but I don't really get why we couldn't have, for example, a non-empty interval as an intersection of all the sets. For instance, considering only the four sets quoted above, why couldn't we have $\bigcap_{n \in \mathbb{N}} I_n = [3.141 , 3.142]$ ? Is it because the theorem considers an infinite numbers of sets? (This being said, even if the answer to this last question should be yes, I would still wonder why we can't find a rational number in the intersection of an infinite number of sets.)

Finally, a last question arised from [this other Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nested_intervals), which says:

> One can consider the complement of each interval, written as $(-\infty ,a_{n})\cup (b_{n},\infty )$. By De Morgan's laws, the complement of the intersection is a union of two disjoint open sets. By the *connectedness* of the real line there must be something between them. This shows that the intersection of (even an uncountable number of) nested, closed, and bounded intervals is nonempty.

I tried to look for what was "the connectedness" of the real line, but I didn't find anything really helpful, and as a result I didn't understand what this part of the article means.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: For the unbounded case, consider $I_n=[n,\infty)$.

Comment: Note that you can fix this by extending $\mathbb{R}$ to contain $\{\pm\infty\}$ because the above interval (and all like it) are no longer closed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Andrés E. Caicedo already gave an example of nested, closed and unbounded interval which does not have any point in the countable intersection.

---

About the intersection part, let $I_n=[a_n,b_n]$. Now, by the construction of $I_n$, we have $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}a_n=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}b_n=\pi$.

Let $x\in\bigcap_{n \in \mathbb{N}}I_n$; then you have $a_n<x<b_n$, $ \forall n\in \mathbb{N}$. Since both limits converge to $\pi$, $x=\pi \notin \mathbb{Q}$. Thus, in the rationals, $\bigcap_{n \in \mathbb{N}}I_n=\emptyset$.

---

This definition of connectedness is probably topological. It says, in your case,  that the real line cannot be represented by the union of two open and disjoint sets. For example, $(-\infty,a)\cup(b,+\infty)\neq\mathbb{R}$, even if $a=b$.